# IE10 automatically submits HTML form

Tags: html, windows-7, internet-explorer-10

Hi I have a fairly simple HTML login form:

```
<form name="login" action="checklogin.php" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Login to Continue</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Username</td>
<td><input name="username" type="text" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td><input name="password" type="password"  value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
```

This works fine in Google Chrome but when it comes to IE10 on Windows 7 the form auto completes and submits. I have checked the obvious auto complete options in IE10 and ensured they are off and all stored information is cleared. However the form still gets auto completed and submitted. Is there some way of explicitly instructing IE10 not to do this?

Comment: IE doesn't submit forms by itself. Are you sure you don't have kind of helper script running?

Comment: Ok got it. This is an HP machine and it was running HP Simple Pass. This installs a BHO Add-in to IE 9+ called "True Suite Website Logon" which was responsible for this behaviour.   Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it. This is an HP machine and it was running HP Simple Pass. This installs a BHO Add-in to IE 9+ called "True Suite Website Logon" which was responsible for this behaviour. Thanks for the help.